# Need To Add System Data and Time to My Powershell Test-NetConnection Output as a Column

Tags: powershell

For my current script (appended below), I need to add an extra column as 'Time' which captures the current system date and time along with the output which the script is already capturing. How can get the desired output (as shown in the image appended in the link). As I will be exporting the data to an excel sheet later on.

My Current Output VS Desired Output

[image: My Current Output VS Desired Output]

The Script:

```
$Target = '192.168.1.19', 'ww.google.com'

$outFilePath = 'Desktop\Ping1.txt'

$result=@()

#$getdate = Get-Date -Format “dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm”

#$getdate| Out-File $outFilePath -Encoding utf8 -Append
foreach ($t in $Target)

{



$a=Test-NetConnection -ComputerName $t -Port 5895 -WarningAction SilentlyContinue

$result+=New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property ([ordered]@{
'Target'=$a.ComputerName;
'RemoteAddress'=$a.RemoteAddress;
'Port'=$a.RemotePort;
'Status'=$a.PingSucceeded 

})

}



$result |  Out-File $outFilePath -Encoding utf8 -Append
```

Answer (score 0):

If you specify date format as: `dd/MM/yyyy`, slash will be recognized as date separator and replaced by date separator from your current culture settings. In my case it would return `06-04-2020`

To circumvent this behaviour, escape the separators. Add this to hashtable you use for generating other properties:

```
Time = (get-date -Format 'dd\/MM\/yyyy hh:mm')
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Could you also tell me how to get this output exported into an excel sheet with the same columns?

Comment: @AbhinavPathak That's another problem, and you could find many answers to this question on SO. I'd suggest to try one of these modules: ImportExcel or PSExcel.