# Powershell Script Yields No Output For Test-NetConnection (To Be Invoked in UiPath)

Tags: powershell, uipath

I am not getting any output for the following script. The current script does not have any path specified to it (It gets the path from the UiPath Workflow). However, even if I specify a path (let's say Desktop\Ping1.txt) all I see is an empty text file. Where is the script going wrong?

Expected result:

[image: Output]

The Script:

```
Param(
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$outFilePath
)
$machineName = "ENC-CAP-COM-01.ee.intern","ENC-CAP-COA-02.ee.intern", "192.168.1.9"
foreach ($t in $machnieName)
{

 if(!(Invoke-Command {param($t) Test-NetConnection -ComputerName $t -Port 5895 -InformationLevel Quiet}))
    { 
        $a=Invoke-Command {param($t) Test-NetConnection -ComputerName $t -Port 5895 -WarningAction SilentlyContinue} -ArgumentList $t

        $result+=New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property 
        ([ordered]@{
        'Time' = (get-date -Format 'dd\/MM\/yyyy hh:mm')
        'Target'=$a.ComputerName;
        'Status'=$a.PingSucceeded 
        })
    }

}
$result |  Out-File $outFilePath -Encoding utf8 -Append
```

Comment: Add a couple of `write-host` statements to see if `$a` and `$result` got populated in the first hand.

Comment: There's a typo `$machnieName`. Should be `$machineName`. And you are not sending the computername parameter `$t` in the first Invoke-Command. And, you asked the exact [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61058923/powershell-script-is-not-providing-an-output-with-the-param-function-also-need-t) yesterday And the [day before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61056085/need-to-add-system-data-and-time-to-my-powershell-test-netconnection-output-as-a)..

Comment: Duplicate question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61058923/powershell-script-is-not-providing-an-output-with-the-param-function-also-need-t) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61056085/need-to-add-system-data-and-time-to-my-powershell-test-netconnection-output-as-a)

Comment: @Theo even after correct the spelling mistake, the script isn't giving an output. Also, $t is being sent in the first invoke command also.

Comment: No, it is not. There is no `-ArgumentList $t` there..

Comment: @Theo thanks, that solved the problem.